# Switch case for a group of inputs?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Given that I have the following finals:

```
private static final char CLIPPING_LOWER = 'c';
private static final char CLIPPING_UPPER = 'C';
private static final char RESET_LOWER = 'r';
private static final char RESET_UPPER = 'R';
private static final char LOAD_LOWER = 'l';
private static final char LOAD_UPPER = 'L';
private static final char QUIT_LOWER = 'q';
private static final char QUIT_UPPER = 'Q';
```

And consider the switch-case:

```
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            char usersChoice = e.getKeyChar();      // get the user's choice 
            switch(usersChoice)
            {
            case LOAD_UPPER:
                {
                    userPressedLoad();
                    break;
                }
            case LOAD_LOWER:
                {
                    userPressedLoad();
                    break;
                }                   

            case RESET_LOWER:
                {
                    userPressedReset();
                    break;
                }

            case RESET_UPPER:
                {
                    userPressedReset();
                    break;
                }

            case CLIPPING_LOWER:
                {
                    userPressedClipping();
                    break;
                }

            case CLIPPING_UPPER:
                {
                    userPressedClipping();
                    break;
                }

            case QUIT_UPPER:
                {
                    userPressedQuit();
                    break;
                }

            case QUIT_LOWER:
                {
                    userPressedQuit();
                    break;
                }                   

            default: 
                break;

            }

        }
```

Is it possible to write a case for both `c` and `C` in one block (and also `r` and `R` ... etc) instead of writing a separate case for `c` and another case for `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user Character.toLowerCase with usersChoice, that way you don't have to handle 'R', 'C', etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char)

Answer (score 3):

One solution to group the cases together

```
case LOAD_UPPER:
case LOAD_LOWER:
    userPressedLoad();
    break;
```

Another solution is to [convert the input to uppercase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) and use only uppercase in switch statement

```
char usersChoice = Character.toUpperCase(e.getKeyChar());

case LOAD_UPPER:
    userPressedLoad();
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case CLIPPING_LOWER:
case CLIPPING_UPPER: {
                    userPressedClipping();
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like this for instance:

```
case LOAD_UPPER: case LOAD_LOWER:
{
    userPressedLoad();
    break;
}
```